# Join в flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть два класса

```
class Authors(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'authors'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name', db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Books(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    isbn = db.Column('isbn', db.String, nullable=False)
    title = db.Column('title', db.String, nullable=False)
    author_id = db.Column('author_id', db.Integer,
                          db.ForeignKey('authors.id'), nullable=False)
    year = db.Column('year', db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, isbn, title, author_id, year):
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.title = title
        self.author_id = author_id
        self.year = year
```

Хочу сделать запрос `books=Books.query.all()`, но что бы я мог достучаться до `Authors.name` при обращении к элементу `books`

Получить название я могу с помощью books[x].title, например, а как потом получить `Authors.name`?

Понимаю, что нужен `join`, но не могу разобраться в синтаксисе, много примеров видел для `sqlalchemy`, но не для `flask-sqlalchemy`

Не хочется синтаксиса вроде `db.session.query(Books,Authors).join()...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ответ](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/) нашелся через `joinedload`

Для этого необходимо было добавить

```
class Books(db.Model):
...
    authors = db.relationship('Authors',
                          backref=db.backref('books', lazy=True))

...
```

И сделать запрос как `Books.query.options(joinedload('authors'))`